# How to write an algebraic function specific to multiple values across multiple variables?

Tags: r

I have two datasets, as follows (in simplified form, believe it or not):

```
df1 <- structure(list(TERMAC_Value = c(122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 
605L), TERMAC_ShortName = structure(c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
17L), .Label = c("AG", "BWS", "DAWS2", "DEMF", "DM", "EAAW", 
"EABT", "EASDS", "EASM", "EEAW2", "KSP", "Marsh", "MAWS", "MEMF", 
"MeWG", "MWS", "PV", "TWS", "WM", "ZM"), class = "factor"), GLOBCOV_Value = c(30L, 
130L, 60L, 140L, 140L, 60L), Glob_ShortName = structure(c(14L, 
11L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L), .Label = c("Bare", "CldBdFrst", "CropVeg", 
"FloodFrt", "FloodGrs", "Grass", "GrassSgrub", "OpBdFrst", "OpNdFrst", 
"RainCrop", "Shrub", "ShrubGrass", "Sparse", "VegCrop", "Water"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

    df2 <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("b1[1] VegCrop", 
"b1[2] Shrub", "b1b2[1,1] VegCrop ZM", "b1b2[1,2] VegCrop PV", 
"b1b2[2,2] Shrub PV", "b2[1] ZM", "b2[2] PV"), class = "factor"), 
    Mean = c(4.0188615, 1.0145846, -0.3134498, 1.1346487, -0.2701251, 
    -0.5978043, -0.06)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

My problem is that I need to calculate a unique value following this formula:

y = 4.05 + b1[i] + b2[i] + b1b2[i,i]

This would be an additional column on df1. So for example, the value for ZM and VegCrop would be as follows:

y = 4.05 - 0.3 + 4 - 0.27

y = **4.23**

So my new dataset would be:

```
TERMAC_Value TERMAC_ShortName GLOBCOV_Value Glob_ShortName   VALUE
          122               ZM            30        VegCrop  4.23
          122               ZM           130          Shrub  etc
          122               ZM            60       OpBdFrst ...
          122               ZM           140          Grass ...
          122               ZM           140          Grass ...
          605               PV            60       OpBdFrst ...
```

I know this can be easily accomplished with some `for` looping across the datasets, but as I have done my best to avoid dealing with `for` loops, I'm now stuck.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The example you gave for AM and VegCrop is hard to understand. How did you come up with those values for b1, b2, and b1b2?

Comment: What exactly is `i` supposed to represent? How did your data get in this way in the first place? The data in `df2` seems to be in a very unfriendly format. What do you do with values for `OpBdFrst` which don't seem to be represented in `df2`?

Comment: @mickey those are values from a Bayes model (run using JAGS) estimating abundance of a species according to that particular predictor. I'm trying to create a (very) rough heat map of abundance using those values (obviously some problems theoretically with this, but I want it in place for later tweaking and refinement)

Comment: @MrFlick I was using "i" there as a representation of, for example, b1 ZM, b1 PV, and etc. As you note, the full dataset has many categories. And my apologies, it's somewhat confusing because of the way I cut the datasets. You're correct that in the full dataset there is OpBdFrst, etc, following on from ZM and PV. For the purposes of this example, I tried to keep it simple and focused on the set up of the formula into which all of those predictors will eventually be plugged in. Hopefully that makes sense.